# Python - change sought after dictionary key when not found

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, iteration

Take the following example:

```
dict = {'1': 'A', '2': 'B', '3': 'C', '44': 'D', '555': 'E'}

code = '12344555'
i = 0

while i < len(code):
    try:
        print(dict[code[i]])
        i += 1
    except KeyError:
        print(dict[code[i] + code[i]])
        i += 2
```

I want to iterate through a code, compare it with a dict and return the apropriate value and if the key is not found it should look if the key can be found when adding an extra element to the sought after value.

My code now works for ABCD but not E, I could add another Try-except but this seems stupid. Is there a better way?

And side question: is there a way to assign a variable (i in this case) inside the while loop construct instead of right before, something like: `while i(=0) < len(code)`

Comment: Is there a limit on how long the key can be? Or should it keep adding characters until the end of the string?

Comment: It should add characters as long as there are characters to add. But Simon Crane provided a great answer. Thanks everyone, amazing community.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Store the string that you are looking up in a variable, and then append bits of the code to it until it matches.

```py
dict = {'1': 'A', '2': 'B', '3': 'C', '44': 'D', '555': 'E'}

code = '12344555'
i = 0
s = ''

while i < len(code):
    s+=code[i]
    if s in dict:
        print(dict[s])
        s = ''
    i+=1
```

I would also add that using try/except to control flow is slower than if/else and generally considered bad practice